# Deploying multiple Helm charts despite duplicated objects

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have **2 helm child charts** and **1 umbrella chart** which depends on both childs.
Unfortunately the both child charts contain duplicated k8s objects (so they also share the *same name*).

So on doing `helm install release1 umbrella` I get `Error: configmaps "x-1" already exists`.

Hint:  We are the authors of the "child" charts (so we can change them) but we can not avoid name collisions.

Is it possible to do `helm install` despite some k8s objects are duplicated ? Could we adapt the "child" charts to make it possible (like "consider this object only if not already defined")

I know it is possible doing it with plain `kubectl` since it will merge the duplicates without errors.

Answer (score 1):

A typical Helm convention is to name objects after both the release name and the chart name.  In a dependency-chart situation, each of the charts will have its own chart name, but all of the charts will share the same release name.

```yaml
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}-x-1
```

If you create a chart with `helm create`, it will include a `"chartname.fullname"` helper in `_helpers.tpl` that helps to construct this name in a standard way.

This approach will get you two separate, non-conflicting ConfigMaps, but they might have duplicated content.

If you want to have only one copy of the ConfigMap, you can move it into its own chart, and have the two "child" charts depend on that.  If the umbrella chart depends on A and B, and A and B both depend on some common dependency C, Helm will only install that dependency once.  The service charts A and B will still know the name of the ConfigMap, since they know the release name (the same as the current `.Release.Name`) and the chart name (the name of the common dependency chart).

```yaml
configMapRef:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-common-x-1
```

Comment: Great idea to outsource the duplicates into a grand-child chart.

Comment: But is there also an other option (without grand-child chart) and not including the {{ .Chart.Name }} into the childrens name ?

Comment: Not really.  What should Helm do if you told it to install two things with the same kind and name, but they're different?

Comment: `"Helm will only install that dependency once"` seems to be not true: I still get `Error: configmaps "x-1" already exists` when outsourcing the common dependency into its own Chart. It may be related to this issue: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2247